# Record computer sounds with Media Foundation

Tags: c#, windows, ms-media-foundation

I'm looking to record a video file consisting from a video channel which is webcam along with an audio channel which is the sounds played on the computer. Is this possible?

Comment: Use WinRT's MediaCapture https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture (it will underneath probably use MF)

Comment: @SimonMourier Isn't that for UWP?

Comment: Short story: no :-) Long story: https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/05/what-is-actually-the-universal-windows-platform-and-what-is-winui-msix-and-project-reunion/

Comment: @Kurubaran That sample works with DirectShow.

Comment: To people who vote to close: The mentioned "duplicate" question is totally different than this one. It's not even about media foundation. Please re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NAudio to do the capturing, the captured samples can be piped to the Media Foundation

Comment: For now I +1 your answer because it seems promising. I'll mark as answer after I get results. Thanks!